# Send notification to user after waiting a certain amount of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, push-notification

I'm completely new to objective-c, and Googling this issue for 2 hours has left me with no useful information. In fact I'm even more confused than when I started. I also have a textbook updated for iOS 6, but it is completely useless for the issue.

I simply want the user to enter a certain time in my app (perhaps from a date picker, I haven't decided yet) and then get a notification later (say, for example, 5 hours before the the time the user enters).

The sample picture below illustrates what I mean. Say the user enters 2:09 am, then, at 9:09 pm (5 hours before), he gets the illustrated notification.

I've found this code, from [this](http://www.smipple.net/snippet/Sounden/Simple%20NSNotificationCenter%20example) source, but I'm not even sure if this is what I need for my purposes:

```
// Add an observer that will respond to loginComplete
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(showMainMenu:) 
                                                 name:@"loginComplete" object:nil];


// Post a notification to loginComplete
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loginComplete" object:nil];


// the function specified in the same class where we defined the addObserver
- (void)showMainMenu:(NSNotification *)note {
    NSLog(@"Received Notification - Someone seems to have logged in"); 
}
```

The code seems to be more for NSNotificationCenter. All it does is print the message to the console after the button press event.

Can someone modify the given code, or provide a sample for how I can get the result I'd like.

You don't have to write my app for me. That's not what I'm asking for. Just code samples, or links to them.

To reiterate, I want the user to enter a time into a control, the app determines when a few hours before that time will be, and at that time, it gives a notification. The controls and time stuff I can figure out, but the notification stuff has me really stumped. That's what I need help with.

If someone has been lucky enough to find a good tutorial on this, that will definitely help me as well.

Given that help on this issue is difficult to find via Google, and that this is probably a common issue for many people, any amount of help will probably benefit not just myself, but others who see this.

Thanks in advance.

[image: notification]

Comment: If you want to use notification in your application than first you should read apple doc for that http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Here apple doc explain how to set local notification http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [`UILocalNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13) for that. here is the [tutorial](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-scheduling-local-notifications-using-a-singleton-class/)

```
     UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    notification.fireDate = self.datePicker.date;
    notification.alertBody = "Wake up!!";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;     
    notification.alertAction= @"view details";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    [notification release];
```

This will schedule a local notification for your app. If your app is in background the system itself will give a alert message. But `If the application is foremost and visible when the system delivers the notification, no alert is shown, no icon is badged, and no sound is played. However, the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: is called if the application delegate implements it.` There you have to respond to the notification.

Comment: Wow I didn't think it would be this easy. This is great, thanks.

Comment: Just one question ... What is the Alarm object typed as? Is there a built in class called alarm, or is the some hypothetical class you're assuming we would implement? For example, you have alarm.message in your sample code.

Comment: Ya alarm is my own class. I just copied the code from my app. `alertBody` `soundName` are just strings :)